# Count percentage of more foreach loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a script that gets the 0-100 percentage of the iteration of more than 1 loop (in my specific case 3 loop):

I show you the Code Sample:

```
int progress = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>>> ad in allDocuments)
{
    Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>> categoriesDocs = ad.Value;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, List<MyStruct>> categoryDocs in categoriesDocs)
    {
       List<MyStruct> docs = categoryDocs.Value;

       foreach(MyStruct doc in docs)
       {
           progress = ???

           //... CODE ....
       }
    }
}
```

How can I calculate progress value with correct percentage?

Comment: you have to calculate the number of total iterations, this is number of most outer ones * number of mid-term iterations * number of inner iterations. Then you can indicate how many percent of that total number you already got.

Comment: FYI you could do `foreach(var categoriesDocs in allDocuments.Values)` to iterate the values of `allDocuments` (assuming that `allDocuments` is a `Dictionary`) and the same can be done for your inner loop as well.  As for the percentage you'd need to first get a total like `allDocuments.Values.Sum(x => x.Values.Sum(y => y.Count));` to use.

Comment: You could also reduce this down to just one loop with `foreach(var doc in allDocuments.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Values.SelectMany(y => y)))` assuming you don't need any of the keys for anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count up the total first, and then you can calculate the progress.

```
int total = 0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>>> ad in allDocuments)
{
    Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>> categoriesDocs = ad.Value;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, List<MyStruct>> categoryDocs in categoriesDocs)
    {
       total += categoryDocs.Value.Count;
    }
}

int progress = 0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>>> ad in allDocuments)
{
    Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>> categoriesDocs = ad.Value;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, List<MyStruct>> categoryDocs in categoriesDocs)
    {
       List<MyStruct> docs = categoryDocs.Value;

       foreach(MyStruct doc in docs)
       {
           //... CODE ....
           
           ++progress;

           double percentComplete = (100.0 * progress)/total;
       }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use Linq to calculate the total rather than writing an explicit loop, you could use:

```
int total = allDocuments
   .SelectMany(doc => doc.Value)
   .Sum(docList => docList.Value.Count);
```

(I've assumed that `allDocuments` is of type `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, List<MyStruct>>>`)

Note that this is no faster than the explicit loop, but some people may prefer it.

Comment: @djv That counts the number of lists, not the sum of the items in the lists.

Comment: This could definitely be simplified (or rather, *shortened*) using Linq, but I wanted to keep it simple for the OP.

Comment: In my opinion it is computationally heavy repeat iterations for 2 times, as said by @juharr   you can find the totalIterations in this way --> allDocuments.Values.Sum(x => x.Values.Sum(y => y.Count));

Comment: @SalvatoreCassano `In my opinion it is computationally heavy repeat iterations for 2 times` What makes you think that the Linq solution isn't also iterating the same elements?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it's true, Sum will, but Count won't. Which is the same as the nested loops in your answer

Comment: @djv Yes indeed, it's the same complexity.